Не ходит ping между моим компьютером и маршрутизатором в GNS3
Создал в GNS3 простую сеть из облака (мой компьютер) и маршрутизатор. Подключился к облаку на предварительно созданный loopback интерфейс, назначил адреса. Маршрутизатор - 192.168.100.1; мой комп - 192.168.100.100.

Пытаюсь пинговать и вижу такую картину.
ping комп-маршрутизатор:

ping маршрутизатор-комп:

То есть если пингует комп, то он получает ICMP reply но при этом ping этого почему-то не видит. Если же пингует маршрутизатор, в ответ на полученные request'ы мой компьютер ничего не шлет. Почему так? Уже кучу времени промучался, в итоге ничего.
